# Visual Studio 2012 cannot access Team Explorer security/group membership sections but Visual Studio 2010 can

Tags: visual-studio, windows-domain, team-foundation-server

I've recently upgraded from Team Foundation Server 2010 to 2012 and Visual Studio 2010 to 2012.

Within Visual Studio 2010 I can still access all of the TFS settings. Within Visual Studio 2012 I can access all sections except "Security" and "Group Membership" under the "Team Project" and "Team Project Collection" headings. Upon clicking any of those I get the error message:

> Team Foundation Error
>
> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password

The same username/password is used in both versions of Visual Studio.

Note: This computer is NOT connected to the domain, although it is using domain credentials for TFS. I've heard that there may be an issue with Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2012 when using domain credentials for the connection but not being logged into the computer as a domain user. Can anyone confirm this or offer any steps that I can try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have experienced a similar issue. The work around that we are now using for it is to run VS using our domain credentials. For some reason, your TFS credentials are not enough when running on machines where you are not logged into the domain.

runas /netonly /user: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"